# How do I show apt-get package management history via command line?

Tags: apt, history

Is there a way to show the history of packages that were changed by apt-get via command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get a list of most recently installed packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17012/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-most-recently-installed-packages)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

All actions with apt (apt-get) are logged. These files are available in /var/log/apt/. To view the most recent history log, execute:

```
less /var/log/apt/history.log
```

These logs gets rotated (every month I guess), old files will be suffixed with a number and compressed. So to view the next history log, use:

```
zless /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz
```

To view the logs available:

```
ls -la /var/log/apt/
```

Comment: This is excellent. The only thing missing is who ran the commands.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement Have a look at /var/log/auth.log, it *may* contain the user running the installation. (this won't help if the installation was invoked through a shell/program running as root)

Comment: Also useful: zgrep, zcat

Comment: does this file also log the dependency packages installed as a result of original apt-get?

Comment: @Mahesha999 It does not, it only logs requested packages. Try /var/log/dpkg.log for the lower level installation details that included dependends.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement the latest versions of APT offer a "Requested-By:" portion of the log to show who invoked the command as well as which command they invoked like "Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages' " or "Commandline: apt upgrade"

Comment: Note that after a reboot, `/var/log/apt/history.log` ceases to exist...

Answer (score 30):

You can also make a short command to display the interesting content.

- Add this custom function to your `~/.bashrc`:

  ```bsh
  ### pars for fun: install | remove | rollback
  function apt-history(){

        case "$1" in
          install)
                grep 'install ' /var/log/dpkg.log
                ;;
          upgrade|remove)
                grep $1 /var/log/dpkg.log
                ;;
          rollback)
                grep upgrade /var/log/dpkg.log | \
                    grep "$2" -A10000000 | \
                    grep "$3" -B10000000 | \
                    awk '{print $4"="$5}'
                ;;
          *)
                cat /var/log/dpkg.log
                ;;
        esac
  }
  ```
- And call it in a terminal like this:

  ```
  kreso@h17:~$ apt-history install
  2013-08-06 14:42:36 install gir1.2-nautilus-3.0:amd64 <none> 1:3.8.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu13.04.1
  2013-08-06 14:42:36 install python-nautilus:amd64 <none> 1.1-3ubuntu1
  2013-08-06 14:42:37 install insync-nautilus:all <none> 1.0.20
  2013-08-07 14:41:37 install powertop:amd64 <none> 2.1-0ubuntu1
  2013-08-07 18:44:10 install libdiscid0:amd64 <none> 0.2.2-3build1
  2013-08-07 18:44:11 install sound-juicer:amd64 <none> 3.5.0-0ubuntu1
  ```

Taken from [here](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-show-apt-log-history.html)

Comment: `zgrep ... /var/log/dpkg.log*`- outputs entries from archives too.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the following command to list recently installed packages

```
grep "\ install\ " /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Comment: even better: `grep "\ install\ " /var/log/apt/history.log` in case you need to copy and paste a list into apt-get

Answer (score 2):

If you want those packages that were installed and *not* subsequently uninstalled, try this:

```
comm -23 <(grep "apt-get install" /var/log/apt/history.log | sed 's/.* //' | sort) \ 
<(grep "apt-get remove" /var/log/apt/history.log | sed 's/.* //' | sort)
```

This is the installs minus any matching removes.

References:

- `comm`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963862/338303
- `<(grep...)` syntax: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73931/redirecting-multiple-commands-as-input

Comment: +1: Nice one-liner but only valid for the last log rotation period. Also instead of `sort`, use `sort -u`in both cases to avoid duplicate lines to show up such as in package like `oracle-java8-installer` and many others.

Answer (score 2):

To get the update history of a specific package assuming it was installed/updated via apt here's a oneliner (bash and zgrep), example is for package skypeforlinux:

```
package='skypeforlinux'; pregex="(${package}[^\)]+\))"; while read -r line; do [[ "$line" =~ ^Start-Date:[[:space:]]([[:digit:]].+) ]] && curdate="${BASH_REMATCH[1]} "; [[ "$line" =~ $pregex ]] && echo "$curdate ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done < <(for i in `ls -tr /var/log/apt/history*`; do zgrep -B3 "$package" $i; done)
```

This greps apt's history log files for skypeforlinux including the previous three lines to get the date. Then iterates over the result and echoes the relevant dates and versions.

Replace the *package* variable value with your package name, even works for multiple packages provided they begin with same string.

Example with output:

```
package='apache'; pregex="(${package}[^\)]+\))"; while read -r line; do [[ "$line" =~ ^Start-Date:[[:space:]]([[:digit:]].+) ]] && curdate="${BASH_REMATCH[1]} "; [[ "$line" =~ $pregex ]] && echo "$curdate ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done < <(for i in `ls -tr /var/log/apt/history*`; do zgrep -B3 "$package" $i; done)
2017-10-19  15:00:09  apache2-utils:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5)
2017-11-24  14:24:45  apache-pom-java:amd64 (10-2build1, automatic)
2018-02-22  16:42:02  apache2-data:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5, automatic)
2018-02-26  15:34:34  apache2:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5)
2018-02-26  15:36:32  apache2-data:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5)
2018-02-26  15:40:50  apache2-data:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5, automatic)
2018-02-26  15:42:07  apache2:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5)
2018-02-26  15:42:39  apache2:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5)
2018-03-15  10:08:50  apache-pom-java:amd64 (10-2build1)
2018-04-20  08:55:07  apache2-data:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5, 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.8)
2018-07-06  08:55:11  apache2-data:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.8, 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you actually do it, say package mutter:

```
_P=mutter &&
(cat /var/log/dpkg.log{,.1};zcat /var/log/dpkg.log.*.gz) |
egrep --text "^[^ ]* [^ ]* (configure|install|remove|status [^ ]*|trigproc|upgrade) $_P[: ]" |
sort --reverse | less
```

Using **dpkg.log** captures operations that apt-get does not see.

Output:

```
2016-12-20 09:47:35 status unpacked mutter:amd64 3.22.2-2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.10.1
2016-12-20 09:47:35 status installed mutter:amd64 3.22.2-2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.10.1
…
```

Comment: Please note triple backticks here don't work the way you think they do.