# Returning Packages To Default

Tags: package-management, configuration, repository

Is there a way to make my system go back to how it was when first installed ubuntu without doing the standard installation again? I want my packages, repositories, configuration files to go back to how it was when `ubuntu 12.04 LTS` was first installed.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Sadly dpkg or apt dosn't keep a log of what packages were installed / removed and when, as far as I know. The best shot here is to look through your .bash_history and try to find what you modifyed. (You do know that `dpkg -l` will show you all packages that are installed configured etc. right?)

To properly purge a package use:

```
apt-get remove --purge <package>
```

To reconfigure ALL packages on your system use the following command (as root):

```
dpkg -l | cut -d " " -f3 | xargs dpkg-reconfigure
```

Be aware that this will possibly take some time.

These tools are capable of getting a lot of configuration "reseted" but they are incapable of magic. If you messed up your system really bad then the best solution sometimes is to back-up everything and reinstall.

---

You can use `dpkg-reconfigure <package-name>` to "reset" most packages to their defaults; but no-one knows what you installed with your systems main install except you.

You could search for which packages a "default" installation puts on your machine and remove everything else, but then again we can't know what you installed with your system's base install.

Comment: But my system knows what packages are installed into it. Can I at least run some commands to reconfigure all of them? My problem is that some configuration files that I deleted manually don't get created again. I tried all `apt-get` commands, `purge`, `autoclean` `install`(again) but they just refuse to be recreated. Is there a solution to that? (pretty annoying) P.S `dpkg-reconfigure postgresql`, postgresql is the annoying package, didn't do it.

Comment: Did you try to purge / reinstall postgre? (You'll want to back up the databses you have before that.)

Comment: Also you might search for your missing config and re-create it manually (restarting postgres after it). It's pretty voodoo, but it might work.

Comment: I did try purge/re-install. As I said I tried all I know with apt-get. I will now try the second option you listed in your edit.

Comment: root@pcomp:/home/deus# dpkg -l | cut -d " " -f3 | xargs dpkg-reconfigure
dpkg-query: error: package name in specifier 'Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold' is illegal: character `=' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold is not installed

Comment: Apt does log the history in `/var/log/apt/history*`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/show-apt-get-installed-packages-history-via-commandline