# Is there a way to tell when I unstalled a program?

Tags: uninstall

Is there a way to tell when I unstalled a program?

I uninstalled a program a whle back, maybe 6 months ago I think, Im wondering if this is recorded somewhere, maybe with what version I unistalled and other details. Is there a way to find that info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull up Ubuntu's Software Center. It shows the whole history of all packages that were installed, upgraded and removed. Click the "History" at the bottom of the list to show.

Comment: What about installing directly with apt-get or synaptic?

Answer (score 1):

For apt-get, check [How do I show apt-get package management history via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/show-apt-get-installed-packages-history-via-commandline).

For synaptic you can find the answer on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto#View_History.