# Checking update reason after actual update

Tags: software-updater

Is there a possibility to find out the reason for at least the last automatic update?

When the update-window pops up one can click on the entries and find a statement about what bug shall be fixed with a certain package, or more general why it is updated at all.
I want to check for this information afterwards to check if a certain bug or functionality is claimed to be fixed already.

thx - robert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly (as Ubuntu does not package the changelog info directly anymore, so this: https://superuser.com/questions/137818/easily-view-a-list-of-changes-of-upgraded-packages won't work anymore), but you can piece the information together yourself.

You can look at the log:

[How do I show apt-get package management history via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/show-apt-get-installed-packages-history-via-commandline)

This is the sample output from my machine:

> Start-Date: 2013-10-29  20:29:59 Commandline: aptdaemon
>   role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.89' Upgrade: upower:amd64
>   (0.9.22-1ubuntu1, 0.9.22-1ubuntu2), firefox-locale-en:amd64
>   (24.0+build1-0ubuntu1, 25.0+build3-0ubuntu0.13.10.1), firefox:amd64
>   (24.0+build1-0ubuntu1, 25.0+build3-0ubuntu0.13.10.1), polly:amd64
>   (0.93.10-0~421~ubuntu13.10.1, 0.93.11-0~424~ubuntu13.10.1),
>   libupower-glib1:amd64 (0.9.22-1ubuntu1, 0.9.22-1ubuntu2) End-Date:
>   2013-10-29  20:30:24

From there you can then look up the packages.
I searched on launchpad.net for "upower 0.9.22-1ubuntu1" and got the following page https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/0.9.22-1ubuntu1

Which then has the following info:

> Cherry-pick two fixes from upstream:
>       - up-client: Really don't overwrite retval with prop values. Properties
>         and property notification via libupower-glib got broken in 0.9.22.
>         Incorrect values were being returned, meaning anything relying on these
>         might do the wrong thing, such as in LP: #1238663
>       - lib: Fix crasher calling _about_to_sleep_sync(). Crash fix.  -- Iain Lane    Mon, 14 Oct 2013 11:41:36 +0100

You can do that for any of the packages that interest you.

Comment: WOW. Thanks a lot for the answer! Very helpful.

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote :)