# Where are the logs for apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management, logs

I would like to know where I can find the logs for the following package managers:

- Synaptic Package Manager
- Ubuntu Software Center
- The logs when using the terminal with `apt-get`

Comment: none of the listed logs in the answers are very verbose.  I think it would be nice to see something like:"
downloading index from http://blah blah
downloading deb http://blah
installing package foo version 1.2.3 from file foo.blah.deb" instead of just lists of packages that were installed.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/show-apt-get-installed-packages-history-via-commandline

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Apt logs can be found in `/var/log/apt/term.log`. To view them with GEdit you can use the command:

```
gedit /var/log/apt/term.log
```

Comment: Could I use cat to view them?

Comment: yes you can man

Comment: Of course, `cat /var/log/apt/term.log` will display the file contents just fine. You may also be interested in `tail -f /var/log/apt/term.log`. This only displays the last few lines (tail) of the file, and, more interestingly, will continually print whatever gets appended to that file. This is quite interesting if you want to "observe" the log.

Comment: use `less`so you can scroll easier.

Answer (score 53):

I like `/var/log/apt/history.log`. It is very concise.

Also note that older logs are archived with `logrotate` once a month. To combine the current `history.log` and all the older compressed `history.log` files you can use `cat` and `zcat` like this:

`cd /var/log/apt && cat history.log > ~/Desktop/allhistory.log && zcat history.log*gz >> ~/Desktop/allhistory.log && cd`

Then you can, for example, use `grep` to find what you need:

`$ grep package_name ~/Desktop/allhistory.log` where you will put what you want in place of `package_name`.

```
$ grep google ~/Desktop/allhistory.log
Upgrade: google-chrome-stable:amd64 (32.0.1700.102-1, 33.0.1750.117-1)
Upgrade: google-chrome-stable:amd64 (31.0.1650.48-1, 32.0.1700.77-1)
Upgrade: google-chrome-stable:amd64 (32.0.1700.77-1, 32.0.1700.102-1)
Upgrade: google-chrome-stable:amd64 (30.0.1599.101-1, 31.0.1650.48-1)
```

And, [Bohr](https://askubuntu.com/users/57704/bohr), in a comment, suggested using `zgrep` directly if one is searching for lines related to a specific package. This works for me assuming I'm searching both `history.log` and its existing archived files for `smtube`:

```
zgrep smtube /var/log/apt/history*
```

Comment: Or run `zgrep` directly.

Comment: If you want your log in cronological order (I think it was just unintentional), the command should be rearranged: `cd /var/log/apt && zcat history.log*gz > ~/Desktop/allhistory.log && cat history.log >> ~/Desktop/allhistory.log `

Answer (score 20):

check the file

```
/var/log/dpkg.log
```

which records all the apt activities, such as installs or upgrades, for the various package managers

also you can view synaptic logs through its gui

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
zcat /var/log/dpkg.log.*.gz | cat - /var/log/dpkg.log
```

or if you want less details:

```
zcat /var/log/dpkg.log.*.gz | cat - /var/log/dpkg.log | grep -E 'install |upgrade |remove '
```

Comment: I do not have zcat in my default 20.04 lts Ubuntu install. Where did that come from?

Comment: you can install it using `sudo apt install gzip`

Comment: OK that means that your answer would just be confusing to anyone. You should have included that you need to install zcat.