# How to find the missing dependencies for all packages?

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

I think I have accidentally messed up my Ubuntu, I wanted to remove TOR so I did
`sudo apt-get remove tor*`
That selected a lot of files, which I think is unrelated to the anonymity network. So I ended up deleting files that other packages need. How can I make a scan for the missing dependencies I have removed?

Comment: The nature of dependencies is such that, if you remove packages that other packages need, then those other packages will also be removed. So unless the process was interrupted, you won't have missing dependencies - although you certainly may have entire missing applications or services.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command you seek is:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

That should attempt to correct for any broken dependencies you have.

Comment: I ran that and it showed nothing to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

As @steeldriver notes and you experienced, the dependencies won't help. But with a bit of luck you may find out what `apt-get remove` did by looking at the logs of apt to be found in `/var/log/apt/term.log*`, as aptly noted
in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/425811/367444).

More answers in the same thread point to further log files, e.g. `/var/log/apt/history.log`, which may be even easier to explore.