# Did the upgrade leave dependency problems?

Tags: dependencies, 15.10, do-release-upgrade

I am upgrading to Wily atm and I noticed a lot of `dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:`. This doesn't sound too good, but as mentioned on [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641352/how-to-find-the-missing-dependencies-for-all-packages#comment917610_641352), I would assume that if a package is removed with a dependent package, that both packages would be removed. So was this also the case with the upgrade? Or did it leave dependency problems behind I should fix? If so, how do I fix them?

---

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @A.B. Added what was requested. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no problem after starting `sudo apt-get update -f` all is fine. You have no dependency problems.

During the upgrade, a dependency has been removed. This problem has been removed by the further process again. This is a completely normal process. Sometimes something needs to be removed forcefully to perform an upgrade.