# Do the newly installed Desktop Environment replaces the older one automatically?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, desktop-environments, mate

I had **gnome Desktop Environment**, and yesterday I installed **mate desktop environment** using the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

Now I'm using **mate**. But what happened to the older one? Is it get auto-deleted or what?

Comment: A comment is appreciable on downvotes.  :)

Comment: Unless explicitly told to uninstall the previous environment is still available. Try the switcher option from the login screen to switch to the previous desktop environment.

Comment: k, I'll try, BTW is it a bad question to ask @AmeyaVS?

Comment: In the output of `apt-get install`, did you see any packages being removed?

Comment: I didn't remember, I just rebooted my system just after it shows me 
Done!

Comment: Then [check the logs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425809/where-are-the-logs-for-apt-get).

Comment: This was the last line just before Done

**0 added, 0 removed; done.**