# Ubuntu 18.04 gets extremely laggy after restart

Tags: 18.04, performance

I have just encountered an issue with Ubuntu 18.04 running extremely laggy upon restart - I assume an updated package is the cause. It's not a CPU (frequency or usage) or RAM issue, those are both fine, so I assume it's a graphics driver problem.

It's practically unusable as it is. Is anyone able to help? Happy to provide outputs from terminal commands.

[APT Logs](https://bin.disroot.org/?4f0cc02ec53a493d#EnbBYeJ5v8uakZZEai7YjAHWFnMZ62WXAtKgzAwKdtQQ)

Comment: Have you recently installed any drivers related to graphics?

Comment: Not that I can see, but the libdrm-* packages did update.

Comment: It would be useful if you can attach [APT logs](https://askubuntu.com/q/425809/256099)

Comment: Pasted the last few days log entries above.

Comment: I can also add that everything seems to work perfectly (password appears as as I type at log in screen) until after the log in screen. As soon as I log in (Gnome default) the lagging starts. Interestingly the mouse movement is not laggy at all.

Comment: OK, so things got worse in that I couldn't use the mouse and keyboard at the login screen, but then I fixed both problems by adding the ubuntu-x-swat repository and running 'apt dist-upgrade' from a recovery boot session.