# How to remove ubuntu-desktop metapackage and all of its dependencies?

Tags: gnome-shell

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS with *xubuntu-desktop* installed

Upgrading *gnome-shell* from **3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3** to **3.34.1-1ubuntu1** broke my system and rendered it unusable. No login display appears (or appears as blank) because *gdm3* freaks out.

Installing *xubuntu-desktop* fixed the problem and revived the system.

Now, the question is: is it possible to remove everything related to ubuntu-desktop that facilitates Ubuntu running on GNOME Shell and re-install it back anew to make it look like nothing happened?

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove ubuntu-desktop
```

commands only remove *ubuntu-desktop* and *aisleriot* *gnome-mahjongg* packages.

Comment: Unfortunately not: An install of Ubuntu Desktop from the normal desktop .iso includes a safeguard *specifically* to prevent folks from erroneously autoremoving their entire desktop. All the stock-install packages are apt-marked 'manual', so they cannot be autremoved.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. So do you suggest removing and then re-installing all of the packages manually through Synaptic Package Manager?

Comment: I would simply look through the apt log, list exactly which packages were upgraded, and downgrade those back to the 18.04 versions. There is no need to "reset" all of the desktop packages.

Comment: Alright, that sounds like a reasonable suggestion. I think you answered to my main question just fine. Could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @user535733 It may be useful for future users if you add some information about how to find these packages from the apt log.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi [How to find and read the apt logs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425809/where-are-the-logs-for-apt-get)