# Missing ubuntu packages after wrong command

Tags: command-line, apt, lts

I messed my ubuntu 18.04LTS after I mistakenly typed

`sudo apt-get remove libpython3.6-stdlib`

This removed about 980 MB of packages and now many packages are missing from my ubuntu. How can I revert it back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are the logs for apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425809/where-are-the-logs-for-apt-get)

Comment: Ouch! ... That is soooo unfortunate. Try `sudo apt install --reinstall python3 ubuntu-desktop` and see if it works... To get a list of recently removed or purged packages run `grep -E "remove|purge" /var/log/dpkg.log`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all traces of python from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321421/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-python-from-ubuntu)

Comment: You probably have had PPA with Pythons on time of 16.04. What is the output of `apt-cache policy libpython3.6-stdlib` ? What is the output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt --include=*.list` and `grep -r '^#.*deb' /etc/apt --include=*.list` ?

Comment: Read the list of packages that will be removed prior to hitting "Y".  The confirmation question is there for a reason.

Comment: short way save your data and install anew.

Answer (score 0):

You may re-install the package by the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpython3.6-stdlib
```