# How to access the folder(s) of Google's Pixel 6a mobile phone from Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: nautilus, 22.04, google, mtp

After plugging Google's Pixel 6a into Ubuntu 22.04 via usb c:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 18d1:4ee1 Google Inc. Nexus/Pixel Device (MTP)
```

A partition called `Pixel 6a` also appears in the left menu of Nautilus. However, clicking on that results in this error message after some time:

[image: error]

**How may I access this mobile phone's folders? It is using Andriod 13 as OS.**

I came across a similar [question for `Pixel 4` on Ubuntu 20.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1351193/541417) and tried its accepted answer but that did not work.

```
$ sudo mkdir -pv /media/Pixel6a
mkdir: created directory '/media/Pixel6a'
$ sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/Pixel6a/ -vv
changed ownership of '/media/Pixel6a/' from root:root to me:me
$ ls -la /media/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root   4096 Nov 17 07:21 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root   root   4096 Oct 24 13:04 ..
drwxr-x---+  4 root   root   4096 Nov 17 06:56 me
drwxr-xr-x   2 master master 4096 Nov 17 07:21 Pixel6a
$ sudo apt install jmtpfs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
jmtpfs is already the newest version (0.5-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
$ jmtpfs /media/Pixel6a/
Device 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee1) is a Google Inc Nexus/Pixel (MTP).
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MtpErrorCantOpenDevice'
  what():  Can't open device
Aborted (core dumped)
```

On Nautilus, the same error msg (as shown above) is also seen.

Comment: To go with @Nmath comment above, and I just tried this out in Nautilus and in 22.04, did you make sure that the phone's USB Preference is set to `File Transfer / Android Auto`?  Once I had my Pixel 6 Pro set to that Nautilus didn't have any issues accessing the files on my phone at all.  You might also want to check your USB cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Terrance, @Nmath, and to this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6nRh60I-fo&ab_channel=WorldofTech), I learnt that I had to enable an Andriod phone feature to solve my issue.

Speaking to the phone, I said "`Hey Google, USB Preference`". Thereafter, the screen appeared and I selected `File Transfer / Android Auto` and Nautilus immediately accessed the Pixel 6a device.

[image: default] to --> [image: fixed]

[image: Pixel 6a]

Comment: Please remember to accept your own answer after 24 hours.