# Ubuntu 22.04 oh, no! something has gone wrong after installing Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

I installed the Nvidia drivers 530 from the Software & Updates from Ubuntu 22.04. After rebooting the PC, I got a white screen with an "oh, no! Something has gone wrong. Please contact the system administrator.".

When I try to use `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F3` to go to the command line, a black screen appears, then the cursor starts blinking and never ends. I found no way to use the terminal. What should I do?

Comment: How about from grub rescue or a live session: mount the disk, remove driver?  Seems to me the most logical method ;-)

Comment: Reboot to a [root shell prompt with networking](https://askubuntu.com/a/92558) and undo the changes you made. If you still need help, edit your question with the details of your attempts. FYI, the appropriate proprietary driver for your hardware would have already been installed when you first installed Ubuntu, unless you rejected third party proprietary drivers during installation. If there was some reason that you performed these actions, it would probably be helpful to know about it.

Comment: I had managed to install Nvidia 530 via GUI, but Cuda was not working when I installed its drivers. So I had to purge Nvidia. When I try installing using ```apt```, this "oh no" appears on reboot. When I try to install via GUI again, I get an error of unmet dependencies.

Comment: I could at least reboot on recovery mode and go back to the previous state by purging Nvidia, but I can't install it properly.

Comment: If you purged the Nvidia metapackage, it probably took a lot with it. Check your apt logs: https://askubuntu.com/q/425809