# how to list all the terminal installed programs?

Tags: command-line

Let's say I’ve installed few things from the terminal and I want to list them so I can remove the installations. how can it be done?

thank you!

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/show-apt-get-installed-packages-history-via-commandline