# log in bounce back due to missing system file

Tags: 14.04, lightdm

I have stupidly uninstalled some system component. And after restart I can not login, every time I typed in the corrected username and password, the login page just bounce back.

I am on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I have tried other solutions which seems to be not applied in my stupid case.

What could I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start at boot into GRUB menu (<kbd>Esc</kbd>)
2. Select the Recovery Mode for your kernel
3. Activate the network
4. Open the root shell
5. Install the uninstalled components

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Could you give some hints. which log file I should check according to this situation. Because I do not know which component is uninstalled. I have access to both internet and a root shell

Comment: "less /var/log/apt/history.log" or "zless /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz" for older logs (Source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/show-apt-get-installed-packages-history-via-commandline)

Comment: gratitude ! it shows that it is the " fcitx " which is removed

Comment: Give me a vote 

Comment: Given!  :P ;-) :D