# Losing Ubuntu after trying to remove kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I tried to uninstall kubuntu-desktop after I decided I didn't want it. I had a hard time doing this and eventually used the terminal to get rid of it. I used some code given to me by someone from this site and it didn't work for me. Instead I saw it start deleting apps from ubuntu-desktop and I so I stopped it. I lost the terminal and had to use xterminal to try to get it back. It's doing that in the background as I write this and I'm really lost. Before I tried to remove it Kubuntu was still on my system, it had replaced ubuntu's icons and grub screen and was causing all sorts of problems, this is why I felt the need to remove it so badly. it would seem I've lost a lot of personal files, and this sucks pretty bad. Is there anything I can do to get these files back? I want to keep my settings and files? I should have a backup from a couple of days before but I don't know how to access it. I don't know what to do, all my apps are gone and I'm worried my files are lost forever. All I wanted to do was use Kubuntu, but it seems I've created a mess out of it. Please help, I have windows installed as a dual boot so I can use that if need be, but I dislike using windows and want to just use Ubuntu.

Comment: boot to recovery mode (with networking), run the commands you were given, and then run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I used the xterminal and was able to get unity back. I was able to open up a newly redownloaded app and I am confirming if my files are intact. So far so good, my files seem to be working. Next I guess, do you know if there is a app history? So i can quickly go through and redownload those? Dropbox isn't working correctly but it seems to be an exception. Also, importantly, do you know how to fully remove kubunt without me destroying my computer again? the grub screen and mismatched icons remain?

Comment: depends on the version of ubuntu you are running. It is almost always easier to leave it alone and re-configure things such as themes then remove . See also - http://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/show-apt-get-installed-packages-history-via-commandline . You are starting to ask multiple questions here ...