# sudo apt-get -f install error, how to remove or reinstall corrupted packages

Tags: apt, dependencies

I need to install `libgl1-mesa-dev` lib on Ubuntu 14.0.4, because  QT 5.5 depends on this lib.
I run following command and gets error, How can i fix this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcheese-dev : Depends: libcheese3 (= 3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1) but it is not installable
                 Depends: gir1.2-cheese-3.0 (= 3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libclutter-1.0-dev (>= 1.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgstreamer0.10-dev (>= 0.10.32) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev (>= 0.10.32) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese-gtk-dev : Depends: libcheese-gtk21 (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu1) but 3.4.1-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libcheese-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu1) but 3.4.1-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgtk-3-dev (>= 2.99.4) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgstreamer0.10-dev (>= 0.10.32) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev (>= 0.10.32) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libcanberra-gtk3-dev (>= 0.26) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese-gtk21 : Depends: libcheese3 (>= 3.3.5) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libcogl9 (>= 1.7.4) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libmx-1.0-2 (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: cheese-common (= 3.4.1-0ubuntu2) but 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: mesa-common-dev (= 10.1.0-4ubuntu5) but 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6 is to be installed
                   Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx (= 10.1.0-4ubuntu5)
                   Depends: libx11-xcb-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-dri3-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-present-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-sync-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxshmfence-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-dri2-0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-glx0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxdamage-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxxf86vm-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: x11proto-dri2-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: x11proto-gl-dev (>= 1.4.14) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Regards,
Davit

Comment: Did you do this - `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: Yes it does' not help, it gives same dependency errors

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions about this issue ?

Comment: One way is to download all the packages externally from packages.ubuntu.com and then, install it

Comment: What is in your `sources.list`? And do you have some files in `sources.list.d`? The most common source of unmet dependencies is bad repositories.

Comment: sources.list where is this file location ? how i can find it ? My issue is not solved yet

Comment: @DavitAzizyan /etc/apt/sources.list is file location for sources.list. Did you follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa/142808#142808) article ? Please try because in your question it shows dependency error

Comment: I have enabled checking for securty updates ind dialog box software-properties-gt, then run sudo apt-get clean, and sudo apt-get -f install and problem is fixed, thank you for your response

Comment: Thank you @MicrosoftLinux for your response, your post help me to solve my issue, ...

Comment: @DavitAzizyan you can show it as useful comment. Sometimes we just need to understand the fundamental & we can solve our problem ourself.

Comment: well , I am new user in askubuntu.com, I will consider your quote

Answer (score 0):

Try to view the last installed packages [[here]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/show-apt-get-installed-packages-history-via-commandline) and determine if  those are the cause of errors, also don't install packages from outside synaptic [except if you carefully log these packages]

If you don't know how to solve problem, post inhere the last installed packages , [whole history is not needed, just last 3 or 4 packages]

Comment: the problem is solved...  I have enabled checking for securty updates in dialog box software-properties-gt, then run sudo apt-get clean, and sudo apt-get -f install, it and problem solved