# 18.04 Severe display issue - impossible to read the screen

Tags: 18.04, graphics, display, amd-graphics

I have been running ubuntu 18.04 for over a year now on my computer: AMD Ryzen 2400G, no dedicated graphics card. Recently, I was seeing if I could install cemu wiiu emulator; it seemed to be working alright until I finally hit go.

At this point, the song I was listening to started stuttering, and the computer pretty much stopped responding, and so I did the classic alt-prtscr-r-e-s-i-u-b. When my computer rebooted I got to the log in screen just fine, but after I logged in, the display was completely messed up. I have attached a picture of it because it is hard to describe with words, (the screen is pretty much unreadable).

Some things I have tried:
restarting, 
rebooting (pulling out power cord)
Starting up in recovery mode - but I don't really know how to use that to actually do any debugging or fix anything
resetting gnome settings
alt-ctr-f1 -> this actually brings up a display that is undistorted, but it only lasts for about half a second before redistorting.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[display with distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NWZp.jpg)

Comment: If the problems started after installing new software, it's likely that it is the cause of the problem.  Have you tried to revert all of those changes made by the installation of the new software?  If you start in recovery mode from GRUB, and if you "enable networking" then you can get to a terminal with root access and internet access.  If you don't enable networking in recovery mode, the system will be mounted read-only and you won't be able to do anything.

Comment: I have tried, but I probably missed something. Is there a way to see what software was installed by date or some other order?

Comment: you can check your [`apt` logs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/how-do-i-show-apt-get-package-management-history-via-command-line), but if you didn't install this software using `apt` or the software center, it wouldn't be recorded there.  In that case, check with the developer of that software for installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually tried to reinstall ubuntu, but after doing this I noticed that there was a gear next to the login window, that appeared to change the graphic settings from gnome to something else. Changing this setting allowed my computer to resume normal operation. Still a little confused ab