# How to fix or reinstall malfunctioning GNOME without reinstalling entire OS?

Tags: gnome, 23.04

I've got an Ubuntu 23.04 installed on my laptop, with the default desktop environment being GNOME. Some time ago I started experimenting with other desktop environments like KDE. When I got back to using GNOME, it turned out many things on GNOME is broken:

- some icons in the menu looks different
- I cannot lock the screen using keyboard shortcut (despite it being properly specified in settings).
- locking it using mouse (using icon in the menu on top bar) seems to be broken too. I need to do this twice; first time just make a screen darker without actually locking screen
- lock screen was replaced by KDE. I want it to look like it was before

How can I bring back GNOME to the state it was before? I don't want to reinstall entire OS, just get GNOME to its defaults.

**What I've already tried:**

- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell`
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell`

I've also used:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
```

to remove gnome-shell and then I've installed it again, but what I've got as a result is GNOME without Ubuntu tweaks (like taskbar on the left) which is not what I wanted. **I'm looking for a way to bring back GNOME version that is shipped with OS installation.**

Also, removing and installing gnome-shell again hasn't fixed my login screen (it's still how KDE set it up).

Comment: It seems that you need to remove the KDE applications, and not the GNOME ones. You can [find the KDE apps you installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/21658/124466). Remove all of them, and reinstall the package `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Thanks @Archisman Panigrani, I had a similar issue. Reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`, per your advice, helped me restore my Gnome visual desktop.