# How to uninstall with apt-get?

Tags: apt, uninstall

I ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 sni-qt:i386
```

But now I want to remove what I've just installed.

What's the command?

Comment: simple `sudo apt-get remove` or `sudo apt-get purge`

Comment: Visit [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17012/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-most-recently-installed-packages)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way would be to edit your command to enter

`sudo apt-get remove gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 sni-qt:i386`

Open your terminal window, press <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> repeatedly until you see your install command, press <kbd>left-arrow</kbd> until the cursor gets to 'install', backspace it out and type 'remove'.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your previous command ,

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 sni-qt:i386
```

Then run only,

```
^install^remove
```

It replaces  `install`   with `remove` from the previous command and  reruns the corrected command.

**Syntax:**

```
^bad^good
```

Comment: But this only works if that was the immediate previous command - if there were other commands entered between then and now, such as "what did I just do" the bash replacement will fail

Comment: that's what i said in my answer. OP only mentioned "i ran this command to install these packages now i want to remove those packages". That's all.