# Install all recent packages installed on other computer.

Tags: apt, package-management

I have some package installed on a computer. I want to install similar packages for other computer.

I can list down all recent packages with this command

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "
```

It will output something like

```
2015-02-18 19:33:46 install login:amd64 <none> 1:4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9
2015-02-18 19:33:46 install lsb-base:all <none> 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6
2015-02-18 19:33:46 install makedev:all <none> 2.3.1-93ubuntu1
2015-02-18 19:33:46 install module-init-tools:all <none> 15-0ubuntu6
2015-02-18 19:33:46 install mount:amd64 <none> 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20
2015-02-18 19:33:46 install mountall:amd64 <none> 2.53
```

This list is quite big.

I want to make it something like

```
sudo apt-get install login lsb-base module-init-tools mount mountall
```

Comment: You need to `cut` that list to get only the name of the packages, and then pass those names into the apt-get install command

Comment: Yes, i am trying to figure out a way to do that. I think awk command can do it but not sure about it. Can you direct me towards a way to do it ?

Comment: `cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep "\ install\ " `

Comment: Take a look at Alvin Row answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/17012/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-most-recently-installed-packages

Comment: thanks, but again it gives me output in several line. problem is I have 1000s of such line. I want to extract all those packages name.

Comment: You will find what you're looking for in the link that i told you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save all the installed packages shown by `/var/log/dpkg.log` in an array:

```
mapfile -t packages < <(grep -Po '.* install \K[^ ]+' /var/log/dpkg.log)
```

Here the array `packages` will contain all the package names.

Now you can simple do:

```
echo "${packages[@]}"
```

to see the package names in a space separated form.

This will work well with `apt-get` command:

```
sudo apt-get install --dry-run "${packages[@]}"
```

The above command will be expanded to:

```
sudo apt-get install --dry-run libntlm0:amd64 libgsasl7:amd64 ....
```

If you have `ssh` access from the new computer to the one where the package are installed, from `NEW` computer you can use:

```
$ mapfile -t packages < <(ssh OLD 'grep -Po ".* install \K[^ ]+" /var/log/dpkg.log'))"
```

This will save the package names from `OLD` computer in the array `packages`. change the `ssh` parameters accordingly.

Now you can simply do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install "${packages[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make it as you wish, there is a better way of backing up a list of programs:

On the First compute run those commands:

```
dpkg --get-selections > /some-path/packages.list

sudo cp -R /etc/apt/sources.list* /some-path/

sudo apt-key exportall > /some-path/Repo.keys
```

Then copy those files to the other computer and there run those commands to install exactly the same apps from the first computer:

```
sudo apt-key add /some-path/Repo.keys

sudo cp -R /some-path/sources.list* /etc/apt/

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dselect

sudo dpkg --set-selections < /some-path/packages.list

sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade -y
```

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections` will list all the packages in any conditions....this will show the packages that were installed automatically, manually, comes preinstalled..OP wants only the manually installed ones..

Comment: @heemayl yes you alright list all the packages in any conditions but I didn't see anywhere the OP asks for manually installed packages. He asked:   `I have some package installed on a computer. I want to install similar packages for other computer.` He didn't say I installed some packages

Comment: OP is parsing `/var/log/dpkg.log`..that is the idea of it all in my opinion..

Comment: Mmmm Maybe you are right, wait for the OP response

Comment: @Maythux Thanks , I only needed manually installed packages but as both computers are freshly installed. I need all the packages on computer1 to be installed on computer2.

Comment: Then I think also my answer would be applicable

Comment: Yes, it is applicable.

Comment: I prefer this answer as it won't include packages that were installed then removed.

Answer (score 1):

command to do this is

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep "\ install\ " | awk '/ install / {printf "%s ",$4 }'
```