# Uninstalled multiple package, need help recovering

Tags: apt, libreoffice, data-recovery

I was trying to uninstall LibreOffice from my Ubuntu 15.04 running Xfce. I typed the following command in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --purge libre*
```

It took a while before I realised that the process was erasing more than I needed, since components such as dpkg, gimp, compiz, have also been removed.

Is there any way to check the extent of the damage that has been done and recover? I must say that I cannot reinstall the operating system at the moment.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get a list of most recently installed packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17012/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-most-recently-installed-packages)

Comment: Not a duplicate: here the OP has uninstalled dpkg; obtaining a list of recently uninstalled packages isn't enough for helping him.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
sudo apt-get --purge libre*
```

does exactly nothing it is wrong

```
E: Command line option --purge is not understood
```

---

If you have used the next command (in my test in a bash shell it does also nothing? ...)

```
sudo apt-get purge libre*
```

use the command below to identify the purged packages for a given date, eg for `2015-08-28`

```
awk '/Start-Date: 2015-08-28/,/End-Date: 2015-08-28/ {if ($0 ~ /Purge/) {sub(/Purge: /,"",$0); print $0}}' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Check the list and reinstall the purged packages via

```
awk '/Start-Date: 2015-08-28/,/End-Date: 2015-08-28/ {if ($0 ~ /Purge/) {sub(/Purge: /,"",$0); print $0}}' /var/log/apt/history.log | awk '{for (i=i;i<=NF;i++) {if (i%2 == 1) {system("sudo apt-get install -y "$i)}}}'
```

---

*Example*

I've started the command below

```
sudo apt-get purge librevenge-0.0-0
```

I get the following output

```
% awk '/Start-Date: 2015-08-28/,/End-Date: 2015-08-28/ {if ($0 ~ /Purge/) {sub(/Purge: /,"",$0); print $0}}' /var/log/apt/history.log
libreoffice-pdfimport:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libmspub-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.1-2)
libreoffice-base-core:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libreoffice:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libwpg-0.3-3:amd64 (0.3.0-3)
libreoffice-writer:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libmwaw-0.3-3:amd64 (0.3.4-1)
libvisio-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.0-2)
libreoffice-impress:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libreoffice-help-de:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libreoffice-base:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
librevenge-0.0-0:amd64 (0.0.1-3)
libreoffice-draw:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libreoffice-core:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libreoffice-gnome:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libreoffice-sdbc-firebird:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libwps-0.3-3:amd64 (0.3.0-2)
unoconv:amd64 (0.6-6)
inkscape:amd64 (0.91-3ubuntu1)
libreoffice-report-builder-bin:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libwpd-0.10-10:amd64 (0.10.0-2)
libreoffice-help-en-us:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libreoffice-ogltrans:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
python3-uno:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libabw-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.0-2)
libe-book-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.1-2)
libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libreoffice-gtk:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
mythes-de:amd64 (20120516-2)
libcdr-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.0-3)
libodfgen-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.1-2)
mythes-en-us:amd64 (4.2.1-0ubuntu3)
libreoffice-base-drivers:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libfreehand-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.0-2)
libreoffice-math:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
libreoffice-calc:amd64 (5.0.1~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid1)
```

Comment: I did use the "purge", not the "--purge" mentioned in the post. However, the awk command only reveals that libreoffice related components were removed.

Still, when I check Ubuntu Software center history, it shows a list of over 100 different components that were removed that day.

Comment: Sorry, answer updated

Comment: I get mostly the same. However, here is the list found in /var/log/dpkg.log  regarding what components have been uninstalled on the very same day. Note that I did not uninstall anything else separately. May it be I didn't correctly understood the listed processes?

Warning, huge list.

http://dumptext.com/kFlf8Jtl

Answer (score 0):

You could just reinstall the lost one, and type this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg gimp compiz
```

and then it might work fine this way.

Comment: Did this, but I suspect there are way more components that have been removed.